# Generalized convex combination over a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, reference-request, lebesgue-integral

**The Question:** Is the following true?  If not, what further hypotheses do I need?

> Let $X$ be a Banach space, and let $C \subset X$ be closed and convex.  Let $P$ be a probability measure over $D$, and let $f:D \to X$ with $f(D) \subseteq C$ be $P$-integrable. Then
>   $$
> \int_D f \,dP \in C
> $$

Intuitively, I believe this should be true since it is a sort of "limit" of convex combinations of elements of $C$.  That is, when $P$ is a discrete measure with finitely many atoms, then this is simply the definition of convexity, and I would think that there is some limit by which we can reach integrals with respect to arbitrary measure.

I am not sure, however, how to formalize this argument.  This seems like something that would pop up in some handy reference, or failing that, it at least it seems like a standard kind of argument of which someone here could fill in the blanks.

At the very least, I would be interested in an argument that works in the case that $X = \Bbb R^n$ (or $X = \Bbb C^n$).

Comment: the integral isn't defined for any Banach space $X$. See Bochner integral and Pettis integral. If it is Bochner integrable, I think it is true. To prove it, you need Hahn–Banach separation theorem, if I remember right.

Comment: @user251257 I did specify that $f$ is "integrable", does that not help?  If that's insufficient, does it help if $D$ is "nice" in some other way?

Comment: oh right. sorry

Comment: We can assume that $f$ is Bochner integrable.

Comment: I suppose this does smell a bit like Hahn Banach separation, but I don't really see where to fit it in

Comment: Probably I just mixed it up and remember it wrong. Can't find a proof right now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll assume real scalars for convenience.  If $y = \int_D f\; dP \notin C$, then by the Separation Theorem there is $r \in \mathbb R$ and  a continuous linear functional $\phi$ such that
$\phi(y) > r$ while $\phi \le r$ on $C$.  But $\phi(y) = \int_D \phi(f)\; dP \le \int_D r \; dP = r$, contradiction.

Comment: Neat!  Thanks for being explicit about how the HB theorem applies.

Comment: It is unclear why $\phi(y) = \int_D \phi(f)\; dP$.

Comment: Ok I got it probably, is it because: 1). $\phi(y)=-\phi(-y)$, 2). $\phi(\Bbb E f)\le \Bbb E(\phi(f))$ due to convexity and 3). replacing $f$ by $-f$ in 2) yields the opposite direction of inequality?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming whatever sort of integral you're talking about satisfies $$\Lambda\left(\int f\right)=\int\Lambda\circ f\quad(\Lambda\in X^*)$$this is immediate from the Hahn-Banach theorem (the disjoint-convex-sets-one-closed-one-convex version):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem#Geometric_Hahn.E2.80.93Banach_theorem

Comment: Is there any reason for using this version of HB as opposed to the more typical incarnation?

Comment: I'm not sure which theorem you're referring to. The one I think of as typical has to do with separating points and subspaces - I don't see how that applies, since $C$ is not a subspace.

Comment: Now that I'm reading the specifics of your link more carefully... never mind.  Thank you for the answer!