# Mean value theorem for vector valued function (not integral form)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

Let $f:U\to\mathbb R^m$ be differentiable with $U\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ being open and convex.

If $f$ is absolutely continuous, then by fundamental theorem of calculus we have following version of mean value theorem: For any $x,x+h\in U$ it follows
$$ f(x+h) - f(x) = \left( \int_0^1 f'(x+t h)  \; d t \right) h. $$
By mean value theorem for integral, we obtain
$$ A = \int_0^1 f'(x+t h)  \; d t  \in \overline{\operatorname{conv}} \{ f'(x+th) \mid 0< t < 1 \}. $$

Is it possible to obtain that result without $f$ being absolutely continuous? That is, assume $f$ is only differentiable. Is the following statement correct?

> For every $x,x+h\in U$ there exists some $A$ in the closure of the convex hull of $\{ f'(x+th) \mid 0< t < 1 \}$ with
>   $$ f(x+h) - f(x) = Ah. $$

Comment: Where did you find the first two statements ?

Comment: @TonyPiccolo fundamental theorem of calculus? most book dealing with Lebesgue integration. mean value theorem for integral? a consequence of Hahn-banach separation theorem. you can find the proof even on math se.

Comment: I know the matter, but wanted to know if you had in mind some particular source. Usually this information helps in answering.

Comment: @TonyPiccolo I tried to adapt the proof for the MVT for integral, like in [that answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1368000/251257). It should work. However, I would like an opinion by someone else.

Comment: The usual formula that I know only says $f(x+h)-f(x)=\int_0^1 f'(x+th)dt h$. I don't see where the $f'(x) h$ on the left hand side of your equation comes from.

Comment: @PhoemueX oh right. my bad. will edit it

Comment: Now you see the true reason of my first comment.

Comment: @TonyPiccolo ah. sorry my bad

Comment: @TonyPiccolo if you could have a look on it again. Do you think that the Hahn Banach argument is correct?

Comment: Differentiability is enough: you should read the article by Furi and Martelli _On the Mean Value Theorem, Inequality, and Inclusion_, A.M.Monthly, November 1991, theorem 5, p. 843.

Comment: @TonyPiccolo thanks. It seems, I have the same idea like they had.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the given (finite dimensional) assumption, we can even obtain
$$ f(x+h) - f(x) \in \operatorname{conv}\{ f'(x+th)h \mid 0 < t < 1 \} = \operatorname{conv}\{ f'(x+th) \mid 0 < t < 1 \}h. $$

Thank @TonyPiccolo for the reference:

[McLeod Mean value theorems for vector valued functions (1965)](http://journals.cambridge.org/article_S0013091500008786).

Comment: The result is valid for general normed linear spaces. If the codomain of $f$ has finite dimension (and yours is the case), then one can avoid considering the closure (of the convex hull) as was shown by McLeod _Mean value theorems for vector valued functions_ (1965). The fact depends on a property of the so called _relative interior_ in the finite dimension case.

Comment: You can read also Flett's book _Differential Analysis_ (1980), prop. (1.6.7), p. 33 and, by the same Flett, the article with the same title as McLeod's (1972) where he studies the question in a more general setting.

Comment: Why did you edit by "only obtain ... instead of ..." ? There is an equivalence: if you take the inner product side by side ...That is, if $C$ is convex, so is $C \cdot (y-x)$ with obvious meaning of the symbol.

Comment: @TonyPiccolo inner product with what? If the vector $Ah$ is a limit of convex combinations of the derivatives times $h$, why should $A$ be a limit of convex combination of the derivatives? If we can let go of the closure, then it is true.

Comment: I'm saying another thing. Don't think of your post now. If $C$ is a convex subset of the space, then $\{c \cdot h : c \in C \}$, where $h$ is an element of the space, is a convex set.

Comment: @TonyPiccolo yes. I agree. But I have never said that it isn't true. I can't follow

Comment: You are right: in fact I was thinking of the case $m=1$. For every $m$, the question is more delicate. The fact is that $f'(x+th) \in L(\mathbb R^m, \mathbb R^n)$. However I don't think your edit is necessary: let's study together (as usual the problem is time).

Comment: The existence of exercise 17(b) on page 348 in C.Pugh  _Real Mathematical Analysis_ (2002) means that I am right, but I must show ... Be patient !

Comment: @TonyPiccolo I will take my time to read the references you provided. Some ad hoc fix in finite dimensional case is, that the derivative is bounded.

Comment: As your edit, it is enough to apply the properties of matrix product, to show it is not necessary: try as an exercise. McLeod's argument is based on the fact that the _relative interior_ of any finite dimensional nonempty convex set is always nonempty ! You must read the sources ...

Comment: @TonyPiccolo I meant to obtain the matrix as limit of convex combination, not to let got of the closure.

Comment: @TonyPiccolo: I went through McLeod's paper and understand the proof. Little bit technical, but much easier in finite dimensional context. Thanks.