# If $f: U \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is differentiable and $\Vert df(x) \Vert \leq K$ for any $x \in U$ then $\Vert f(x) - f(y) \Vert \leq Kd(x,y)$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> Given an open set $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{m}$ connected by paths, consider the metric in $U$ given by
>   $$d(x,y) = \inf_{\gamma \in C(x,y)}\int_{0}^{1}\Vert \gamma'(t) \Vert\text{d}t$$
>   where $C(x,y)$ is the set of the curves $C^{1}$ by parts $\gamma: [0,1] \to U$ such that $\gamma(0) = x$ and $\gamma(1) = y$. Show that if $f: U \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is differentiable and $\Vert df(x) \Vert \leq K$ for any $x \in U$ then $\Vert f(x) - f(y) \Vert \leq Kd(x,y)$ for any $x$ and $y$ in $U$.

**My attempt.**
$$\|f(x) - f(y)\| = \left\|\int_{x}^{y}f'(t)\text{d}t \right\| = \left\|\int_{0}^{1}f'(\gamma(t))\|\gamma'(t)\|\text{d}t \right\| \leq \int_{0}^{1}\|f'(\gamma(t))\|\|\gamma'(t)\|\text{d}t \leq K\int_{0}^{1}\|\gamma'(t)\|\text{d}t.$$
Now, since $\gamma$ is arbitrary, we can choose $\gamma$ such that $\int_{0}^{1}\|\gamma'(t)\|\text{d}t = d(x,y)$?

My solution seems too simple. I suspect something is wrong.

Comment: The second expression does not make sense if the segment joining $x$ and $y$ does not  lie in $U$ (moreover, it is unclear what $f'(t)$ means here). Nevertheless, your argument is almost correct: Take $\gamma\in C(x,y)$ realizing almost the infimum (in general, it isn't a minimum) and write $\|f(x)-f(y)\|=\|\int\limits_0^1 (f\circ \gamma)'(t)dt\|. Then apply the chain rule and the triangle inequality for the integral.

Comment: But $f$ is assumed to be differentiable, not *continuously*  differentiable. So the integral may not exist!

Comment: @JensSchwaiger, I see! Do you have any hints?

Comment: Approxomate the path $\gamma$ by a piecewise affine one and use the generalized mean value theorem.

Comment: Probably https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1395163/mean-value-theorem-for-vector-valued-function-not-integral-form could be helpful.

Comment: Taking $\gamma$ same as @Jochen hint, we have $\|f(y) - f(x)\| = \|f(x + h) - f(x)\| = \|\int_{0}^{1}f'(x + th)\text{dt}\|$ by Jens Schwaiger hint, so, $\|f(y) - f(x)\| = \|\int_{0}^{1}(f\circ \gamma)'(t)\text{d}t = \|\int_{0}^{1}f'(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)\text{d}\| = ...$, Is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let first $\gamma\colon[0,1]\to U$ be continuously differentiable. Then one may choose some $\delta>0$ such that for all $t_0=0<t_1<\ldots<t_{n-1}<t_n=1$ with $t_{i+1}-t_i<\delta$ there is some  $r>0$ such that the ball $B(\gamma(t_i),r)$ is a subset of $U$ containing $\gamma([t_i,t_{i+1}])$. Then $\Vert f(\gamma(t_{i+1}))-f(\gamma(t_i))\Vert\leq K\Vert\gamma(t_{i+1})-\gamma(t_i)\Vert$ for all $i$ since $B(\gamma(t_i),r)$ is convex. Thus $\Vert f(\gamma(1))-f(\gamma(0))\Vert\leq K\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\Vert\gamma(t_{i+1})-\gamma(t_i)\Vert$. Taking the supremum of the LHS we get $\Vert f(\gamma(1))-f(\gamma(0))\Vert\leq K \cdot\text{length}(\gamma)$, where the length of $\gamma$ is the supremum of the lengths of all *inscribed* polygons which is the same as
$\int_{0}^{1}\|\gamma'(t)\|\text{d}t$. If $\gamma$ is piecewise continuously differentiable one may apply this result to the corresponding pieces.

Thus you get  $\Vert f(\gamma(1))-f(\gamma(0))\Vert\leq K \int_{0}^{1}\|\gamma'(t)\|\text{d}t$ for all $\gamma\in C(x,y)$. Taking the infimum over $\gamma$ finishes the argument.